# Uninstall a 3rd party software-Macbook

Tags: audio, macbook

I installed a software to record internal sound along with screen recording in Macbook (Installed Software: [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases)).

But since I have installed the software, something is going wrong with my macbook. It is keep hanging. I want to remove the software but it is not available in the Applications folder.

How can I remove it? The software name is appearing in the list of speakers as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of Soundflower (or find the .dmg you installed it from, can go [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/soundflower/downloads) to download), and on the disk image there is an uninstall script. Run that and it should remove it. If it opens Script Editor, just click the "play" button on the window to run it. Then restart your computer and it should be gone.

BTW, Soundflower has not been updated since 2012 and causes a lot of issues with newer OSes, I do not recommend using it anymore. [iShowU Audio capture](https://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204161459-Installing-iShowU-Audio-Capture) is one free alternative that may work better.

Comment: I already tried to do that but still, it did not get uninstalled.

Comment: It's possible the script is outdated due to the lack of updates and being set up for an older OS... You may have to look at the paths and actions being referenced in the script and either update paths if they're outdated or run the actions manually if it's not behaving properly.

Comment: It also might be that you have to disable System Integrity Protection, run the uninstall script, then re-enable it. This could be preventing the modifications. I don't have the script, could you copy the code from Script Editor and paste it here so I can tell what it's doing?